# Unable to connect to Google Websites (i.e. YouTube, Drive)

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns, connection, network-adapter

Experiencing a very weird issue on my desktop, running Win 10. Every so often I will be unable to connect to Google pages like Drive, Calendar or even YouTube, when that happen I can still access Gmail and all other sites like CNN, Facebook etc. This will be the case for all the browsers on my system (Chrome (default), Edge, Firefox). I will get the error message I am unable to connect to the webpage.

I have tired to renew/release and flush DNS and that sometimes works but not all the time. Sometimes i need to kill my wifi connection and remove it from my list and start new. What is weird is if I connect my desktop to my mobile setup as a hot spot it will connect and pages will display.

All other computers, tablets, mobile phone will not have any connection issues, they will connect to all Google pages.

I am using Google Wifi, my desktop is setup for Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), even setup IPV6. (2001:4860:4860::8888,2001:4860:4860::8844) Network card is Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168. I even removed the drivers for this card and installed them again. I have checked the connection of all other devices to the same bridge I am connected and teh conenctions toi the webpages will work.

I ran antivirus software, malware and nothing shows up. (Malawarebytes, Bitdefender) Cleaned registry. My next step is resetting my Google Wifi to factory settings and starting over, I am not certain that is the solution since only this PC is unable to connect.

Chatted with Google who had me assign an IP to my desktop and changed the setting to ISP DNS, also rest my network to ISP DNS. Same issue

Located in Canada

Any ideas?

Thank you

ERROR This site can’t be reached The connection was reset. Try:

Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall Running Windows Network Diagnostics ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Try resetting your Winsock instead of uninstalling your wifi from a cmd prompt or PowerShell __netsh winsock reset__ then reboot.

Comment: I did run the  netsh winsock reset command it did not resolve the issue. Factory reset the Google Wifi, removed Chrome and issue still persist,